# Unable to connect from socket.io-client on local machine to socket.io on Azure Web App

Tags: node.js, azure, websocket, socket.io, client-server

I am trying to get a socket.io server hosted as an Azure Web App to communicate with a socket.io-client on my local machine. I've tested the code between two computers on my local network and it works fine... The client sends a message to the server and the server responds with OK. However when I load the server files using continuous deployment and try to connect with it, the client is unable to connect and I get no feedback in terms of what is going on.`io.on('error, function(){};` doesn't even trigger.

Here's the code for the Client (I've just modified the IP address):

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://160.23.1.5:3100');
var readline = require('readline'),
rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);

socket.on('connect', function(){
     console.log('Connected to Server!');
});
socket.on('error', function(){
     console.log('Erorr connecting to server');
});

socket.on('DATA', function (data) {
     console.log(data);
/// **** Code for  entering client input
});
rl.setPrompt('Server says> : ');
rl.prompt();

rl.on('line', function(line){
socket.emit('RANDOM', {value: line});


rl.prompt();
}).on('close', function(){
console.log('Have a great day!');
process.exit(0);
});
```

Here's the Server code:

```
var http = require('http')
var port = process.env.port || 3100;
var app = http.createServer(function(req, res, err) {
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });

if(err)
{
  res.writeHead(500);
  return res.end('Érror loading server')
}
res.end('Hello World\nActual port is ' + port + '\nEnv port is ' +            process.env.port +'\nType of port variable is ' + typeof(port));

}).listen('3100');

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

var clientSocket;

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  clientSocket = socket;
  console.log('Client connected!');
  socket.on('RANDOM', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('DATA', { RESPONSE:'OK'});
  });
});
```

I've so many different changes and read so much material and now I'm out of ideas. Is anyone familiar with this situation? Please help.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this.  I am getting the same issue.